# Make <div> invisble if there no content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently redisigning a page - making it so JS handles the upload of the content from a txt file and CSS formats the layout of divs and HTML contains the divs. What i am trying to do is hide the DIVs that DO NOT have any content in it - currently if tehre is no content it will still display the div as a long thin line. I've tried several suggestion, however having trouble of making it work properly. Have tried 'empty cell' option in CSS, but that ruins the layout for some reason.

Here is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>BROADCAST</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="BCdata/WebStyles.css">
    <script src="jquery-ui/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="BCdata/ContentHandler.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="main">


<!--------------------------------DONT CHANGE UNLESS NEEDED-------------------------------------------------------------->
<div id="buttons_div">

<!------------------Banner---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
<img src="images/broadcastbanner.gif" id="Image35">
<span id="CurrentDate"></span>
</div>

<div id="buttons_div" style="top:10px;">
   <!------------Archive Calendars----------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
<a href="./BroadcastArchiveCalendar.html"><img src="images/broadcast2013archive.gif" id="Image4"></a>
<a href="Broadcastarchivecalendar2014.html"><img src="images/broadcast2014archive.gif" id="Image5"></a>

<!--------------Signoff Sheet------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
<a href="\\vmsint01\tc_contacts\Documents\BroadCast Signoff Sheet\Broadcast Mgt Sign-off.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="images/broadcastsignoff.gif" id="Image6"></a>

<!----------------------Up and Home-------------------------------------------------------------------------------> 
<a href="./main_tradecounter.htm"><img src="images/Up.GIF" id="Image2"></a>
<a href="./main_tradecounter.htm"><img src="images/Home.GIF" id="Image3"></a>
</div>
```

```
<!-------------------------------------------CONTENT DIVS------------------------------------------------------------------>
<div id="content_divs" style="top:20px; background-image: url(images/bluebox.png);">
    <p id="div1" style="color:white;"></p>
</div>


<div id="content_divs" style="top: 30px; background-image: url(images/whitebox.png);">
    <p id="div2"></p>
    <p id="div2"></p>
</div>


<div id="content_divs" style="top: 40px; background-image: url(images/redbox2.png);">
    <p id="div3" style="color:white;"></p>
```

```
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS

```
#CurrentDate
{
position: absolute; 
top:15px;
left: 210px;
width:700px; 
text-align: center; 
z-index: 8;
color:white;
font-family:Arial;
font-size:35px;
text-transform: capitalize;
}

.main
{
background-color: #FFFFFF;
background-image: url(backbox.gif);
color: #000000;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
overflow: auto;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
top: 10px;
}

.main #content_divs
{
position: relative;
text-align: left;
z-index: 1; 
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
border-style : solid; 
border-width: 3px; 
border-color: white;
overflow: hidden;
}

h1 
{
font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 20px;
font-weight: bold;
position: relative;
text-transform: capitalize;
font-weight: bold;
z-index: 5;
}

h2 
{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 13px;
font-weight: bold;
position: relative;
z-index: 5;
}

p 
{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 13px;
position: relative;
z-index: 5;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-right: 20px;
}

#buttons_div
{
position: relative;
}

#Image35
{
position:relative;
border: 0px #000000 solid;
width: 960px; 
height: 96px;
z-index: 2;
}

#Image2
{
border: 0px #000000 solid;
position: relative;
left:30px; 
width: 90px; 
height: 34px; 
z-index: 3;
}

#Image3
{
border: 0px #000000 solid;
position: relative;
left:30px; 
width: 86px; 
height: 34px; 
z-index: 4;
}

#Image4
{
border: 0px #000000 solid;
position: relative;
left:-30px; 
width: 236px; 
height: 34px; z-index: 5;
}

#Image5
{
border: 0px #000000 solid;
position: relative;
left:-30px; 
width: 236px; 
height: 34px; 
z-index: 6;
}

#Image6
{
border: 0px #000000 solid;
position: relative;
left:-30px; 
width: 236px; 
height: 34px; 
z-index: 7;
}
```

This is JS (content handler)

```
$(function()
{
    $("#div1").load("BCdata/Content061114.txt .Div1 #p1");
});


$(function()
{
    $("#div2").load("BCdata/Content061114.txt .Div2 #p1");

});

$(function()
{
    $("#div3").load("BCdata/Content061114.txt .Div3 #p1");

});

$(function()
{
    $("#CurrentDate").load("BCdata/Content061114.txt #CurrentDate");

});

onload=function()
{
    var content_divs=document.getElementById('Div2');
    if(!div2.hasChildNodes()){content_divs.style.display='none'}
}
```

And this is a TEXT file where content is located

```
<span id="CurrentDate">thursday 6th november 2014, wk 40</span>

<!----Use <p> tag for indentation of a text, otherwise use <div> tag------>

<div class="Div1">

<div id="p1">
    <h1 style="color:white;">Congratulations to 66!</h1>

    <div>PDFs of 'Record Weeks' are now available on the Intranet.</div>

    <h2>Heading 1</h2>

    <p>Content is here</p>

    <h2>Heading 2</h2>

    <p>Content is here</p>


    <div><b><i>Click the link on the right to view PDFs</i></b></div>


</div>

</div>


<div class="Div2">

<div id="p1">

    <h1 style="color:black;">Poster</h1>

    <div>Poster Content</div>

</div>

</div>


<div class="Div3">

<div id="p1">

    <h1 style="color:white;">heading Content is here</h1>

    <div>Content is ehre blabla</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Any help is much apreciated - sorry if it seems that i am asking to fix the problem for me, but i am new to this and very keen to learn. Been stuck on this for a while now

Comment: Can you isolate the problem part and only have a specific and minimal example of the issue?

Comment: Loop through all the divs (if you only want the search to apply some divs, apply a class to them and search for divs with the class). Check if the div is empty and if so, set style.display to "none"

Comment: The thing is i am not sure where the problem lies - which part of the code is not working - most likly the JavaScript - thats why i thought it would be prudent to upload as much content as possible. Sorry for it being so big

Answer (score 3):

You could try **:empty** pseudo-class.

```css
div:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div>div with content</div>
```

Reference: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty)

Comment: note that Internet Explorer < 9 does not fully support these pseude-classes

Comment: it seems the OP has some div with empty paragraphs inside: I suppose he want to hide those containers, but :empty won't work in that scenario.

Comment: If there are contents inside `<div>` javascript is the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work.

```
elementList = document.querySelectorAll('div'); 
for(var i = 0; i < elementList.length; i++)
{
var element = elementList[i];
(element.children === 0) ? element.style.display = "none": element.style.display = "block";
}
```

What this does it get all Div elements, puts them in an array, then checks each one, if it does not have a child it sets display to none, if it does it sets display to block.

**EDIT**

If you don't want it to mess with divs with children atall, just change if statement to:

```
 (element.children === 0) ? element.style.display = "none": "";
```

We use **.children** because this only returns Element objects (aka HTML tagged stuff) and not 'absolutely' every child.

Answer (score 1):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/y7mgmm2u/

thanks to @emmanuel

```css
*:empty {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p><span></span>

    </p>
</div>
<div>test</div>
<p></p>
<p>test</p>
```